# In GNU make is it possible to invoke the same program with different command line parameters?

Tags: unix, gnu-make

Toy Example:

prog.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo $*
```

makefile:

```
%.sh_log:   %.sh
    sh $< $(OPTARGS) > $@ 2>&1

targ1:      OPTARGS=hello world
targ1:      prog.sh_log

targ2:      OPTARGS=goodbye
targ2:      targ1 prog.sh_log
```

When I make `targ2`, `targ1` is executed as expected but since the result of that is `prog.sh_log`, the dependency for `targ2` is satisfied and it does not fire. Since make is based on timestamps, how would one use the same program with different parameters in separate parts of the makefile. My real world program is a multistep program which takes the steps numbers as command line parameters. Due to changes in source systems, I have added other programs between steps.

Comment: You need to make sure you're depending on a *different* rule. It might be necessary to use `define` or something to dynamically generate rules, but you might be able to get away with using a *variable* to contain the command and arguments, or even just splitting `$%` in the first place.

Comment: Me is confused (easily done). Are you saying that the recipe for `targ1` uses `prog.sh_log`, and that the recipe for `targ2` uses a _different_ `prog.sh_log`? Then _make_ dependencies aren't going to help you. Sounds more than a little dubious. You should at least produce a `prog.sh_log_targ1` and a separate `prog.sh_log_targ2` methinks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the command to be run only once, dont make it a target in the makefile:

```
targ1:      OPTARGS=hello world
targ1:
        sh prog.sh $(OPTARGS) > prog.sh.log 2>&1
        echo > $@

targ2:      OPTARGS=goodbye
targ2:      targ1
        sh prog.sh $(OPTARGS) > prog.sh.log 2>&1
        echo > $@
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that a rerun of targ2, say due to error, would automatically run targ1. In the real world that would not work as targ1 would have already done its job, say, it may have inserted rows into the database. It can be simulated here by running targ2 and touching prog.sh.

Comment: No, if the file targ1 exist that target will not be remade at a second attempt to create targ2. So if it is important for you not to rerun a previously successful targ1 you will need to make sure that a file called targ1 is saved. I will edit my answer to save targ1 and targ2 as files.